# MySql Select where Item is in a List

Tags: mysql

I would like to do a query much like this

```
SELECT * from TableA WHERE ColumnA IN (LIST)
```

Essentially I want to build a comma seperated list or something and make sure that the value in ColumnA is in that list.

I could do a sub query but I already have the list i need in my application and dont want to query for it again.

Comment: So, what *exactly* is your problem? Converting a known string into a comma-separated list, or otherwise?

Comment: What is your application?  PHP with PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily.

If your `ColumnA` data type is some sort of text data type, you should write your program to generate a query like this:

```
SELECT whatever FROM TableA WHERE ColumnA IN ('brillig','slithy','tove','gyre')
```

Note the comma-separated list of strings, and note that the strings are delimited with `'` single quotes.

If you're using bind variables you need to bind string variables. The prepared query will look like this.

```
SELECT whatever FROM TableA WHERE ColumnA IN (?,?,?,?)
```

There's no magic to use lists as bind variables (except in ColdFusion). You'll need to bind the variables one by one.